# SQL Group by Year

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008, group-by

This is my query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, cast(date as datetime), 3)
FROM shoptransfer 
GROUP BY year (date)
```

I want to group by the year part of the date (`varchar`) column, however I get the following error:

> Column 'shoptransfer.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How do I group by the year part of the date column?

Comment: See also [sql-grouping-by-month-and-year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406170/sql-grouping-by-month-and-year?rq=3)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

How about:

```
select datepart(yyyy, [date]) as [year]
from shoptransfer 
group by datepart(yyyy, [date])
```

Or:

```
select count(*) as qty, datepart(yyyy, [date]) as [year]
from shoptransfer 
group by datepart(yyyy, [date])
order by [year]
```

This is based on OP's command: *"I want to group by year part of date (varchar) column"*

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with where SUBSTRING(productcode, 5, 3) like '%'?

Comment: @user589983 - no point asking me, it's the OP's query, I just kept his example code as-is but fixed so that it would `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I want to select the complete date you are just selecting year part of date.

Comment: @zain - your post says `"want to group by year part of date"`, that's what I've shown you how to do. Perhaps you could reword your question and explain exactly what you want.

Comment: @zain - sample input data and a sample of what you want to achieve never hurts

Comment: your query group by year fine!But it only select year **datepart(yyyy, [date])**  not date **CONVERT(varchar,cast(date as datetime),3)
**That is my requiremnet

Comment: @zain - You can't have both grouped by year AND the individual dates in the result because they're aggregated.

Answer (score 2):

With MariaDB:

```
SELECT year(date) FROM cost GROUP BY year(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about T-SQL, but in SQL in general, what is in the group by clause must exactly match each non-aggregate function column in the select clause. Try

```
select CONVERT(varchar,cast(date as datetime),3)
from shoptransfer 
where 
SUBSTRING(productcode, 5, 3) like '%'  group by CONVERT(varchar,cast(date as datetime),3)
```

also, `where SUBSTRING(productcode, 5, 3) like '%'` is not filtering out much - maybe remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select both the date and the year you should not use a GROUP BY clause as it combines all of the rows with similar years into one row.  If you want all of the dates with similar years together you can use an ORDER BY:

```
SELECT DATEPART('yyyy',date) AS Year,date
FROM shoptransfer
```

OR

```
SELECT DATEPART('yyyy',date) AS Year,date
FROM shoptransfer
ORDER BY DATEPART('yyyy',date) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add column `shoptransfer.Date` into group by clause.

```
select CONVERT(varchar,cast(date as datetime),3)
from shoptransfer 
where 
SUBSTRING(productcode, 5, 3) like '%' 
group by CONVERT(varchar,cast(date as datetime),3)
```

Comment: thanks!but this will group by date not year. (+1 for encouragement)

Answer (score 0):

```
group by
substring(CONVERT(varchar,comuln1,101),1,4)
```

**year**
2004
2005
2006

Comment: this is not working.problem is we can  only group by column that we are selecting.