# Sql Query : Group by Month & Year for this case

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table **Product** with the following columns

```
ProductId Name RegistrationDate UnregistrationDate
1          AB    2013-01-01      2013-03-01
2          CD    2013-01-10      2013-03-13
```

etc

I would like to get a list of **Registered Products** per every month of a year.

Example : Year , Month and the number of dealers which are registered and not unregistered.

```
Year Month RegisteredProucts
2013  2         35
2013  3         45(includes products even registered before March 2013)
```

I wrote the follwing stored procedure to find the Registered products for one month:
& it works :

```
@Begin Time = First Day of the Month
@End Time = Last Day of the Month


select COUNT(DISTINCT P.ProductId) as RegisteredProducts from Product P    
where ((P.RegisteredDate < @EndTime)
AND (P.UnregisteredDate > @EndTime))
```

I then  wrote the query below but it seems to group the results by the RegisteredDate.
I would like to know how I can group registered products (which are not unregistered) by the end of each month 
for a duration of one year ?

```
select YEAR(P.RegisteredDate) AS [YEAR],MONTH(P.RegisteredDate) AS [MONTH],       COUNT(DISTINCT P.ProductId) as RegisteredProducts from Product P    
where ((P.RegisteredDate < @EndTime)
AND (P.UnregisteredDate > @EndTime))  
group by YEAR(D.RegisteredDate), MONTH(D.RegisteredDate)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL grouping by month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406170/sql-grouping-by-month-and-year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH    months (mon) AS
        (
        SELECT  CAST('2013-01-01' AS DATE) AS mon
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(month, 1, mon)
        FROM    months
        WHERE   mon < DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
        )
SELECT  mon, COUNT(productId)
FROM    months
LEFT JOIN
        registeredProducts
ON      registrationDate < DATEADD(month, 1, mon)
        AND (unregistrationDate >= mon OR unregistrationDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY
        mon
```

Comment: Thanks ! This solution works ! Could you tell me what I can do if I want to limit the mon to the current month dynamically . example : I want to get products only till march 2013 and not beyond march 2013 , as april 2013 is still in progress .

Answer (score 1):

```
; with  months as
        (
        select  cast('2013-01-01' as date) as dt
        union all
        select  dateadd(month, 1, dt)
        from    months
        where   dt < '2014-01-01'
        )
select  *
from    months m
cross apply
        (
        select  count(*) as ProductCount
        from    Product p
        where   p.RegistrationDate < dateadd(month, 1, m.dt) and 
                (
                    UnregistrationDate is null
                    or UnregistrationDate >= m.dt
                )
        ) p
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/92257/2/0)

Comment: Thank you for taking time and demonstrating it in SQL Fiddle  ! The solution works too ! I havent used cross apply till now . Could you tell me if there is a way to dynamically limit the number of months. Example : I would only like to get registered products till the month of March 2013 currently and not beyond that