# How can I show a output from a specific date?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I want to show the code below for every first of the month.
So for April it will have its own 'display_count_pending_outer'
and once May 1st arrive it will show a new one 'display_count_pending_outer'.
In the image I would like to show it every 1st of the month.

```
<cfquery datasource ="Intranet" name="GetDeptSubmissions">SELECT * FROM CSEReduxResponses</cfquery>
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="GetPending">SELECT * FROM GetDeptSubmissions WHERE status = 1 AND execoffice_status = 0</cfquery>
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="GetApproved">SELECT * FROM GetDeptSubmissions WHERE status = 1 AND execoffice_status = 1</cfquery>
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="GetDenied">SELECT * FROM GetDeptSubmissions WHERE status = 1 AND execoffice_status = 2</cfquery>


<cfoutput>

    <div>
        <div class="display_count pending_outer">
            <div class="display_count_desc pending_inner">Pending</div>
            <cfif GetPending.RecordCount gt 0><a href="cse_execoffice_pending.cfm"></cfif>
                <span class="display_count_number">#GetPending.RecordCount#</span>
            <cfif GetPending.RecordCount gt 0></a></cfif>
        </div><!--- /div class="display_count" --->
        <div class="display_count approved_outer">
            <div class="display_count_desc approved_inner">Approved *</div>
            <cfif GetApproved.RecordCount gt 0><a href="cse_execoffice.cfm?approved"></cfif>
                <span class="display_count_number">#GetApproved.RecordCount#</span><br>
            <cfif GetApproved.RecordCount gt 0></a></cfif>
        </div><!--- /div class="display_count" --->
        <div class="display_count denied_outer">
            <div class="display_count_desc denied_inner">Denied</div>
            <cfif GetDenied.RecordCount gt 0><a href="cse_execoffice.cfm?denied"></cfif>
                <span class="display_count_number">#GetDenied.RecordCount#</span><br>
            <cfif GetDenied.RecordCount gt 0></a></cfif>
        </div><!--- /div class="display_count" --->
    </div>
</cfoutput>
```

Right now it shows like this
[image]

Comment: What happens when you run the posted code?

Comment: I don't think you provided enough information to get a good answer.  I would recommend that you look at the TSQL function `DatePart`.  For example `SELECT DATEPART(day, GETDATE())` returns 9 (9th of April).  Your query might look something like `SELECT * FROM GetDeptSubmissions WHERE status = 1 AND execoffice_status = 0 AND DatePart(day, YourDateColumnHere) = 1`

Comment: Right now it post all the data from all the months in one div

Comment: Now that we see what it does show, what should it show?

Comment: I want it to show for each month, for example if its may 1st it will create a new div. So one div per month, each will have the date for each.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're taking the long way to your data. Right now, you're selecting everything in that table, then filtering it down based on `WHERE status=1 and the value of execoffice_status`.

Instead, since all you are after is the total number of records associated to each `execoffice_status`, you can write your query this way:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS total_count, execoffice_status
FROM 
    CSEReduxResponses
WHERE 
    status = 1
GROUP BY 
    execoffice_status
```

Which should return 1 record for each unique value of `execoffice_status` in the table. If this query is correct so far, what you need to do next is [GROUP BY whatever date column you have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406170/sql-grouping-by-month-and-year).

```
SELECT 
    CAST(MONTH(date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS theDate,
    COUNT(*) AS total_count, 
    execoffice_status
FROM 
    CSEReduxResponses
WHERE 
    status = 1
GROUP BY 
    CAST(MONTH(date) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(date) AS VARCHAR(4))
    execoffice_status
```

All you may need to do is add an `ORDER BY` clause and a date range to the `WHERE` clause to further filter down your results. Using CF to output this data should be a breeze at this point.

Comment: thanks so much! Is there a way i an put the dates in the WHERE clause to not be hardcoded and go by the system date? right now i have it (execoffice_date BETWEEN '2014-04-1' AND '2014-11-3')

Comment: SQL Server uses getDate() to return the current db server date and time. You may need to format it to match your stored date formats.

Comment: Thanks, even though I don't think this will solve my problem.From what i have change.

Comment: ColdFusion also has a number of functions that will enable you to determine start and end date variables based on the current date.  Google "coldfusion date functions" to see what they are.