# Sum over values by month in milliseconds

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have table with Values and Date. Values in `Integer` and date is `Integer` in `milliseconds` from 1970's... 
I need to get sum(value) for each month and i haven't any idea how to do it with date in milliseconds. Is it possible?
Thanks.

My table "entry"

```
amount    |   date    
----------------------------
300       |   1390075200000
150       |   1390132500000
20        |   1391075200000
...       |   .............
```

What i want to get:

```
01.2014  |  450
02.2014  |  20
....
```

Comment: The timestamp from 1970's (in milliseconds) can't be supported by `Integer`...It must be cast to `Long`. Am I correct?

Comment: I thought so. But integer work fine and return correct dates...

Comment: Its okay...you want month value from timestamp right?

Comment: Yes. I want to sum total ammount of "Value" for every month

Comment: Can you post your code snippet..what you have tried yet...I know how to get month from timestamp?

Comment: I think i need something like `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM entry ORDER BY date` but i have no idea what should be in `date`

Comment: I think , this can't be done from database query, i.e. `Select` statement. You need to do this programmatically.

Comment: Bad news for me. Ok, thanks.

Comment: can you change to format of the date to a string `yyyy-mm-dd` or add this value in an additional column? then you could use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5406280/1515052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to [convert](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) the dates into [a format supported by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) so that you can extract the month:

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m', date / 1000, 'unixepoch') AS month,
       SUM(value) AS sum
FROM entry
GROUP BY 1
```