# Select a group of values from a specific month using Sqlite Query

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-sqlite

I have a database with different transactions order by date :

column 1 : transactions amounts

column 2 : dates (in milliseconds)

I want to Sum all the transactions of a specific month. For example : January 2015. My problem is the same as this post : [Sum over values by month in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220501/sum-over-values-by-month-in-milliseconds) but i don't arrive to adapt it to my problem and my reputation doesn't allow me to interact with the post.

Here is my code :

```
public int getIncomeOfMonth(int monthnumber) {

    int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

    Cursor cursorIncome = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT sum(amount) FROM " + MyDbTable +
            " WHERE " + " strftime('%" + year + "-%" + monthnumber + ", " + COLUMN_DATE + "/ 1000, 'unixepoch') ", null);


    int positiveTransacSelectedMonth = 0;

    if(cursorPositiveTransac.moveToFirst()) {
        positiveTransacSelectedMonth = (cursorPositiveTransac.getDouble(0));
    }

    return positiveTransacSelectedMonth;

}
```

I've read the documentation on the Sqlite website, but can't find a way to understand. Can you explain me how to use strftime in my case or correct my code ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, storing date in milliseconds is not a good idea. In according to the [Sqlite documentation (section 1.2)](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), you should store your date in one of the following ways:

- TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
- REAL as Julian day numbers.
- INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

After that, it doesn't metter how you actually store your dates, you can always manage it using [strftime](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

In your case you can use the following code:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions 
WHERE strftime('%m', transactionDate) = '05' // replace '05' with your month
```

Look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f838d/2), I have just created. As you can see there, the datetime can be stored in different ways, but the strftime can act over all datetime in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to calculate your range first and use `BETWEEN`, like this:

```
public int getIncomeOfMonth(int monthNumber) {
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.add(Calednar.MONTH, monthNumber)
    long start = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    long end = calendar.getTimeInMillis()

    Cursor cursorIncome = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT sum(amount) FROM " + MyDbTable +
            " WHERE " COLUMN_DATE + " BETWEEN " + start + " AND " + end, null);


    int positiveTransacSelectedMonth = 0;

    if(cursorPositiveTransac.moveToFirst()) {
        positiveTransacSelectedMonth = (cursorPositiveTransac.getDouble(0));
    }

    return positiveTransacSelectedMonth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this query:

```
"SELECT sum(amount) FROM" + MyDbTable +
"WHERE " + COLUMN_DATE + " between date('"+year +"-"monthNumber+"-01') and 
date('"+year +"-"monthNumber+"-01",'start of month','+1 month','-1 day')"
```

or something like that, try to get this:

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM test WHERE date(date) 
BETWEEN date('2015-01-01') AND date('2015-02-01')
```

I can't test the code right now, sorry.