# How to find out sum in a group by function monthwise?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the table `TRANSACTIONTABLE` are three columns: `VendorID, TransacDate, Amount`. The output I require is the data which will contain the sum(Amount) group by vendor but should be month-wise. The output should be somewhat like this: The columns will be..

```
 VendorID, JAN'14, FEB'14, Mar'14 and so on....
```

I have tried the following: `SELECT VENDORID, SUM(AMOUNT) from TRANSACTIONTABLE where TRANSACDATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'`.... Then again for feb, mar and so on. Then I copied the result on to an excel doing a vlookup each time. This is taking time.

Each month column will contain the sum of amount for that particular vendor for that particular month. Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: please make an attempt.

Comment: What are your inputs, outputs and queries you tried so far.

Comment: I have tried the following:   SELECT VENDORID, SUM(AMOUNT) from TRANSACTIONTABLE where TRANSACDATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'.... Then again for feb, mar and so on. Then I copied the result on to an excel doing a vlookup each time.

Comment: You should probably read about PIVOT in sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a table

```
Create Table Transactions (VendorID INT, TransactDate Date, Amount money);
```

then add some sample data

```
INSERT INTO  Transactions (VendorID, TransactDate, Amount) VALUES           
   (1 ,  '2014/01/01', 1.00)
  ,(1 ,  '2014/01/10', 10.00)
  ,(1 ,  '2014/01/20', 100.00)
  ,(1 ,   '2014/02/01', 2.00)
  ,(1 ,  '2014/02/10', 20.00)
  ,(1 ,  '2014/02/20', 200.00)
  ,(2 ,   '2014/02/01', 2.00)
  ,(2 ,  '2014/02/10', 20.00)
  ,(2 ,  '2014/02/20', 200.00)
  ,(2 ,   '2014/03/01', 3.00)
  ,(2 ,  '2014/03/10', 30.00)
  ,(2 ,  '2014/03/20', 300.00);
```

Since there is already an answer to [group by month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5406232/819887) on SO this part was easy:

```
Select VendorID, Year(TransactDate) as Year
     , Month(TransactDate) as Month
     , Sum(Amount) as SumAmount 
FROM Transactions
Group By VendorID 
  , Year(TransactDate)
  , Month(TransactDate);
```

To create columns for each month you can use `pivot` or `select case`. You can [read up on pivot in this article](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/10/pivot-and-unpivot-in-sql-server/) on this [answer on dba.stackexchange - a stackoverflow sister site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31765). I fitted it to your data:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( Select VendorID, Year(TransactDate) as Year 
         , Month(TransactDate) as Month
         , Sum(Amount) as SumAmount 
    FROM Transactions
    Group By VendorID
          , Year(TransactDate)
          , Month(TransactDate)) as Src
PIVOT (
  Sum(SumAmount)
  FOR Month IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
) AS MPivot;
```

### Fully working demo

I used **[sqlfiddle to create a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a522/12)**, please consider to donate to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce the result row wise then try following script.

```
SELECT VENDORID, DATENAME(MM,GETDATE())+''''+RIGHT(CAST(DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR),2) AS [Month],SUM(AMOUNT) AS [Sum] 
 FROM TRANSACTIONTABLE
 GROUP BY VENDORID,DATENAME(MM,GETDATE())+''''+RIGHT(CAST(DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR),2)
```

You can arrange the result column wise by doing little more effort like using some loop. But if you want your query should return the result column wise then **PIVOT** in sql server may be helpful.