# how to get monthly compare display in asp.net chart

Tags: sql-server, group-by

In my Table I have a column name `Transdate` its contains Transaction date in format dd-mm-yyyy. and i am using chart to display the transaction month wise,
i have used the query as.

```
SELECT 
    [p].Transdate AS [Month/Year] ,
    Sum([p].Litres) [Total Sale]
FROM CustomerPoints AS [p] 
INNER JOIN Customers AS [c] 
    ON [c].[CustomerID]=[p].[CustomerID] 
WHERE 
    [p].Transdate BETWEEN '2013-01-20' AND '2015-03-05'
    AND [c].DistributorID = '1'
GROUP BY [p].Transdate 
ORDER BY [p].Transdate ASC
```

The above query gives me data in date form 
.

```
Month/Year         Total Sale      
1-02-2012          500
2-02-2012          500
```

and i want as

```
Month/Year          Total Sale
02-2012              1000
```

i.e I want query to calculate sum(total sale) month wise not date wise.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406170/sql-grouping-by-month-and-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SQL Datepart()/ Month()/Year()

```
SELECT 
   CAST((MONTH([p].Transdate)+'-'+YEAR([p].Transdate)) as VARCHAR(50)) AS [Month/Year],
   SUM([p].Litres) [Total Sale] 
FROM CustomerPoints as [p] 
INNER JOIN Customers as [c]
           ON [c].[CustomerID]=[p].[CustomerID] 
WHERE [p].Transdate BETWEEN '2013-01-20' AND '2015-03-05' 
AND [c].DistributorID='1' 
GROUP BY CAST((MONTH([p].Transdate)+'-'+YEAR([p].Transdate)) as VARCHAR(50))
ORDER BY [p].Transdate ASC
```

Or

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CAST((DATEPART(MONTH,[p].Transdate))as VARCHAR(50))
+'-'+CAST((DATEPART(YEAR,[p].Transdate))as VARCHAR(50))) AS [Month/Year], 
    SUM([p].Litres) [Total Sale]
FROM CustomerPoints as [p] 
INNER JOIN Customers as [c]
           ON [c].[CustomerID]=[p].[CustomerID] 
WHERE [p].Transdate BETWEEN '2013-01-20' AND '2015-03-05' 
AND [c].DistributorID='1'
GROUP BY CAST(CAST((DATEPART(MONTH,[p].Transdate))as VARCHAR(50))
+'-'+CAST((DATEPART(YEAR,[p].Transdate))as VARCHAR(50))) 
ORDER BY [p].Transdate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SELECT 
   CAST((MONTH([p].Transdate)+'-'+YEAR([p].Transdate)) as VARCHAR(50)) AS [Month/Year],
   SUM([p].Litres) [Total Sale] 
FROM CustomerPoints as [p] 
INNER JOIN Customers as [c]
           ON [c].[CustomerID]=[p].[CustomerID] 
WHERE [p].Transdate BETWEEN '2013-01-20' AND '2015-03-05' 
AND [c].DistributorID='1' 
GROUP BY CAST((MONTH([p].Transdate)+'-'+YEAR([p].Transdate)) as VARCHAR(50))
ORDER BY [p].Transdate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
Cast((Datepart(Month,[p].Transdate)) as varchar(50))
+'-'+ Cast((Datepart(Year,[p].Transdate))as varchar(50)) AS [Month/Year]
,Sum([p].Litres) [Total Sale]
FROM CustomerPoints as [p] 
Inner Join Customers as [c]
on [c].[CustomerID]=[p].[CustomerID] 
where [p].Transdate between '2013-01-20' AND '2015-03-05' 
AND [c].DistributorID='1'
GROUP BY Cast((Datepart(Month,[p].Transdate)) as varchar(50)) + '-'+ Cast((Datepart(Year,[p].Transdate))as varchar(50))
ORDER BY Cast((Datepart(Month,[p].Transdate)) as varchar(50)) + '-'+ Cast((Datepart(Year,[p].Transdate))as varchar(50)) ASC
```