# T-sql find duplicate records when dates are in the same month and year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a T-SQL statement to find duplicate record when dates are matched to the same month and year.

I managed to find duplicates if dates are exactly the same in Ms Access using this:

```
SELECT
    First(dbo_T_TrainingMandatory.StaffID) AS [StaffID Field],
    First(dbo_T_TrainingMandatory.TrainingCourseID) AS [TrainingCourseID Field],
    First(dbo_T_TrainingMandatory.DateTrained) AS [DateTrained Field],
    COUNT(dbo_T_TrainingMandatory.StaffID) AS NumberOfDups
FROM dbo_T_TrainingMandatory
GROUP BY dbo_T_TrainingMandatory.StaffID,
         dbo_T_TrainingMandatory.TrainingCourseID,
         dbo_T_TrainingMandatory.DateTrained

HAVING (((COUNT(dbo_T_TrainingMandatory.StaffID)) > 1)
AND ((COUNT(dbo_T_TrainingMandatory.DateTrained)) > 1));
```

But haven't found a solution when the day of the month are different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL grouping by month and year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406170/sql-grouping-by-month-and-year)

Comment: duplicate, can probably be solved by applying [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113045/how-to-return-the-date-part-only-from-a-sql-server-datetime-datatype?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434118/select-statement-to-find-duplicates-on-certain-fields?rq=1). OP seems to be in need of translation from msaccess/jet dialect to tsql too.

Comment: No i can mange between the two languages just fine thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree this is technically a duplicate, the posts listed provide older methods of achieving this outcome.

This should do it:

```
;WITH myCTE ([StaffID Field],[TrainingCourseID Field],[DateTrained Field],[NumberOfDups]) AS
(
    SELECT StaffID,
           TrainingCourseID,
           DateTrained,
           COUNT(2) OVER(PARTITION BY StaffID, TrainingCourseID, DATEPART(YY,DateTrained),DATEPART(MM,DateTrained))
    FROM dbo_T_TrainingMandatory
)

SELECT * 
FROM myCTE
WHERE NumberOfDups>1
```

If you are seeing `1900-01-01` in your data, that means the date is blank.  If blank dates are acceptable, but you want to omit them here, add `WHERE DateTrained <> '' AND DateTrained IS NOT NULL` inside the CTE.

Comment: Thanks you nailed the problem on the head.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to get duplicates

```
; with cte as (
SELECT StaffId,DateTrained, row_number() over (partition by month(DateTrained), year(DateTrained) order by DateTrained) as rn from tablename
) select staffId, DAteTrained from cte where rn > 1
```

Comment: @ Kannan Kandasamy that gives me 8000 rows of the duplicate date 1900-01-01 00:00:00