# Group by year without year() function [Web-SQL]

Tags: sql, web-sql

I want to group by year and count all orders from each year.

I found this: [SQL grouping by month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406170/sql-grouping-by-month-and-year) but all the answers use functions that don't work in WebSQL.

I tried to run this:

```
SELECT to_char (OrderDate, 'YYYY') AS y, count(*) ordCnt // and year
FROM [Orders]
group by OrderDate
order by ordCnt desc
```

Here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all
but there's no `to_char` function.

I also tried this:

```
SELECT Date(OrderDate, '%Y') AS y, count(*) ordCnt
FROM [Orders]
group by y
```

But it produces nulls only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web-SQL is really SQLite.  I would expect the following to work:

```
SELECT strftime(OrderDate, '%Y') AS y, count(*) as ordCnt
FROM Orders o
GROUP BY strftime(OrderDate, '%Y');
```

Comment: @shinzou . . . Perhaps `orderdate` does not have the data in it that you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the sum of Quantity Grouping by OrderDate Daily/Monthly/Yearly report using WebSQL Sample data from
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Daily

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d',OrderDate),SUM(od.Quantity)
FROM [Orders] o
JOIN [OrderDetails] od on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
GROUP BY STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d',OrderDate)
```

Monthly

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%Y-%m',OrderDate),SUM(od.Quantity)
FROM [Orders] o
JOIN [OrderDetails] od on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
GROUP BY STRFTIME('%Y-%m',OrderDate)
```

Yearly

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%Y',OrderDate),SUM(od.Quantity)
FROM [Orders] o
JOIN [OrderDetails] od on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
GROUP BY STRFTIME('%Y',OrderDate)
```