# To find the count of a column based on the months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 columns. Column A with dates from 3 different months and column B with usernames. I want the count of the "usernames" With respect to the three Months. For example, Count of usernames for the 4th, 5th and 6th month respectively. any inputs are much appreciated.

```
Dates   Username    Count
6/10/2018   a   
6/11/2018   b   
6/12/2018   a   
6/13/2018   c   
5/3/2018    e   
5/4/2018    f   
5/5/2018    e   
4/21/2018   g   
4/22/2018   h   
4/23/2018   i   
4/24/2018   g
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: Hint : `GROUP BY` with `MONTH()`.

Comment: I only tried for single month first, which i didnt get the o/p. So was little confused. Not sure if my approach is correct . select Date
      ,Count(UserName)
  FROM [Table Name]

  where 'date' like  '06/11/2018%'

  group by DATE, username;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*), username, month(dates)
group by username, month(dates)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample input implies that you want a monthly count, but at the same level as the original data.  In this case, we can try using `COUNT` as an analytic function, with the partition being the month and year.

```
SELECT
    Dates,
    Username,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), Dates, 126)) count
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: That _is_ more accurate than mine, even though mine answers the question as asked :-)

Comment: I don't actually know what the OP wants...pretty sure it's one of our answers though.

Comment: Tim,might be I get something wrong, but I'm pretty sure, you did not want to use `YEAR(Dates) + '-' + MONTH(Dates)`. The `-` is implicitly casted to `0` and this would lead to integer arithmetics... Maybe `CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),Dates,126)`?

Comment: @Shnugo That sits better with me.  I got that code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406170/sql-grouping-by-month-and-year), which it has been highly upvoted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The output should be lik for 6th month = 4users, 5th month = 3 users and 4th month = 4 users. But i am unable to get a solution for this